# PDF failing to be loaded because it can't be read by PDDocument

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

So the problem im facing right now is as follows.

At work in our project we have a system made for reading pdf-s and printing them and all. Now all of this seems to be working, BUT when trying to print static pdf-s which have for some I get the error **startxref not found**... I have inspected the pdf-s and they seem to be in order. 
The startxref reference is at the end of the file where it should be. 
Only thing i found weird is that it has more EOF-s and startxref-s.

But thats because of Adobe. Because its appending the newer versions of the PDF after the previous.

We are using `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` to load the file in. But nothing gets filled. No trailer no startxref no nothing. It just can't read it. 
And it does not happen for all the files. Some PDF-s are version 1.6 some are 1.4 . 
I suspected that the file might be corrupt. But no. Checked it online with some validators and it checks out.

And at this point I'm clueless as to what the problem could be. I'm just wasting time with it at this point. 
Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Here is the code being used. Nothing special. But when trying to load the part of the pdf are not loaded into the  < pdfTemplate >

```
PDDocument pdfTemplate = PDDocument.load(file);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

// Get field names
List<PDField> fieldList = acroForm.getFields();
List<PDPage> pages = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

process.processPage(company, templateFile, pdfTemplate, acroForm, fieldList, pages, args);

COSDictionary acroFormDict = acroForm.getDictionary();
//((COSArray) acroFormDict.getDictionaryObject("Fields")).clear();

return pdfTemplate;
```

And here is the PDF. Its just a static PDF with some legal information for the client.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B57cf1nqGbC4SEYtemxwQjFQNkU

**update/edit:**

Iv also tried loading the PDF using pjx ( the version/jar used is pjx-200030817.jar ) as a byte array. As it was done in the previous version of the project ( when it worked ). But the result is the same sadly. 
The code is as follows :

// Static PDF

```
String pdfFileName = printDescriptor.getPdfFileName();
byte contents[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(context.getResourceAsStream("/" + pdfFileName));
pdfInput = new PdfInputBuffer(ByteBuffer.allocate(contents.length), pdfFileName);
intermediateFiles.add(new PdfManager(new PdfReader(pdfInput)));
```

Thank you in advance!!! And if i was not clear enough on some point i will clarify.

Comment: Please share some example documents for inspection. And also your pivotal code for opening them.

Comment: Im not sure if I can add attachments to the question yet, in all honesty.

Comment: You cannot attach PDFs to stack overflow questions. Usually one puts the PDF onto a public file share (without ads, e.g. a public google drive or dropbox share) and shares the URL here.

Comment: Please also indicate which PDFBox version you use.

Comment: 1.8.8 is the version used in the project. Iv actually tried another means of loading the pdf. But the same error shows up. Il update the question.

Comment: I just ran your code using PDFBox 1.8.8 and 1.8.12. In both cases the PDF could properly be loaded. The code then choked on `acroForm.getFields()` which threw a `NullPointerException`, and it did so for the simple reason that the PDF contains no form definition and, therefore, `acroForm` was `null`.

Comment: That makes total sense. Seems something else is the problem. I tried reading it in more than one way and i get the same error. I need to look into this more heavily. But thank you anyways :)

Comment: If you insist on using an 1.8.* version then use `loadNonSeq(file, null)` to load documents.